# Google search website redirect for the exact product or categories

Tags: magento2, search, google-analytics, google-api

I am using magento 2 for my online store and how can I configure when customer search some product in google it will show the exact link for the product like ebay.

[image] lIke this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by Rich Snippets.You need to add some meta data in your product view page so it can be identified by google. You can read more about rich snippets here.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-content

https://www.verticalrail.com/kb/rich-snippets/

http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/04/magento-2-rich-snippets/

http://www.razorsocial.com/rich-snippets-and-seo/

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Cant we do it without any extensions

Comment: You can write your own code to add rich snippets. other wise you may use any ready made extension.

Comment: any tutorials do you know where can i follow

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/increasing-speed-and-adding-rich-snippets-in-magento--cms-22244 
This is magento 1 tutorial for rich snippets you may get an idea from it and do same for magento 2.